# React-native, cant run project. Error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

Firstly i cant understand why people use this technology, as for me native apps more better) So i have old project and i need to run this project. Simple task, but i have spent 3 days and still unsuccess. So, please give me some advice, I'm vary sad.

So my error:

> 'GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h' file not found

[image]

My pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'SetPoint' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  rnPrefix = "../node_modules/react-native"

  # Install additional dependencies
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  pod 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-Core', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/React/CoreModules"
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/NativeAnimation"
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Blob"
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Image"
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/LinkingIOS"
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Network"
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Settings"
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Text"
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/Libraries/Vibration"
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/"
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/cxxreact"
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsi"
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor"
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/jsinspector"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => "#{rnPrefix}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  

  target 'SetPointTests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

i made:

```
rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build && cd ios && pod install && cd ../
```

and

```
pod updates
```

it doesnt help me

try to run project:

```
react-native run-ios
```

**UPD**

the bridging header file doesnt help, still have the same issue

[image]

Comment: Have you create the bridging header file?

Comment: @LucaDavanzo thks for comment. What do you mean? Header search path?

Comment: I had to link a screenshot, so I create an answer, take a look

Comment: Have you open Project.xcworkspace file? Be sure of this. Also, have you try running from xcode? Does it works?

Comment: @LucaDavanzo yes, i opened Project.xcworkspace. No, from xCode i clear and build project. I Try to run project from webStorm console, in my project `react-native run-ios`

Comment: @LucaDavanzo form console error: In file included from `/Users/nesalexy/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:24:
/Users/nesalexy/Desktop/myproject/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/GoogleUtilities/Logger/Private/GULLogger.h:22:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULLoggerLevel.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the bridging header on your project

[image]

You can create it manually, is a normal header file that should be named `<ProjectName-Bridging-Header>`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and solved by removing firebase dependencies

```
# Install additional dependencies
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
```

After that run

```
pod install
```